# Can you use the FeatureGate decorator in Azure functions from Feature Management libary from Microsoft?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

Currently I haven't had any success with the feature gate decorator outside of an API endpoint and while in my situation to use it on my Azure functions is rather redundant I was wondering if it was possible rather than sensible?

Using the manager/config dependency is great, but like simplicity of the decorator.

```
[FeatureGate(FeatureFlags.MyFeatureFlag)]
    [FunctionName("MyFunctionHandler")]
    [MyExponentialBackoffRetry()]
    public async Task RunAsync(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("myfunctions/functiondata", "myfunctiondemo", Connection = "SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING")]
        requestModel request,
         MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
         string messageId,
         string lockToken,
         ILogger logger
        )
```

Comment: Could you please refer this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core.md#controller-actions .

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT The link you provided refers to controllers which what I meant by API endpoints. It dosn't definitely awnser my question. I suspect the awnser will be no but I wanted to be sure. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes its related to controllers , There is no sample related to Feature Gate with azure function . In this case we can use feature flag instead it seems, Please refer this MS DOC:  [Add feature flags to an Azure Functions app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process) ,May it helps

Answer (score 0):

> Can you use the `FeatureGate` decorator in **Azure functions** from
> Feature Management libary from Microsoft?

- Currently there is no samples available for  `FeatureGate` decorator to use with Azure function.
- Instead of that we can use `Feature flag` with Azure function  .

To get started please refer this MS DOC:  [Add feature flags to an Azure Functions app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process) & [Use feature flags in an ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x) .